# Is there a way to dynamically create a counter if such "month" exists?

Tags: java

I would like to enquire or get some reference as to how can I dynamically create a counter for each month if the exists ? Currently, I am retrieving the dates from a CSV file and store it in an ArrayList, from there I am comparing the dates to check whether if such month exists. If the month exists then "counter++". Afterwards, store the counter in a hashmap. I understand my code currently is an inefficient way of coding. How could I make it better ?

**CODE**

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> getDataPoint() {
    //My function code
    HashMap<String, Integer> numberOfPost = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int janCounter = 0;
    int febCounter = 0;
    int marCounter = 0;
    int aprCounter = 0;
    int mayCounter = 0;
    int juneCounter = 0;
    int julyCounter = 0;
    int augCounter = 0;
    int septCounter = 0;
    int octCounter = 0;
    int novCounter = 0;
    int decCounter = 0; 
    String pattern = "MMM";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

    OpenCsvReader reader = new OpenCsvReader();
    ArrayList <STPost> STArray = reader.loadST("file_path");

    Iterator STitr = STArray.iterator();
    while (STitr.hasNext()) {
        STPost St = (STPost) STitr.next();
        Date retrievedate = St.getTime();
        String strDate = sdf.format(retrievedate);
        if(strDate.equals("Jan")) {
            janCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("Feb")) {
            febCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("Mar")) {
            marCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("Apr")) {
            aprCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("May")) {
            mayCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("June")) {
            juneCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("July")) {
            julyCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("Aug")) {
            augCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("Sept")) {
            septCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("Oct")) {
            octCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("Nov")) {
            novCounter++;
        }
        else if (strDate.equals("Dec")) {
            decCounter++;
        }
        numberOfPost.put("January", janCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("Feburary", febCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("March", marCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("April", aprCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("May", mayCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("June", juneCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("July", julyCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("August", augCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("September", septCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("October", octCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("November", novCounter);
        numberOfPost.put("December", decCounter);
    }
  return numberOfPost
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of months and check if value exists there using `indexOf` method.

```
String months = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
Integer idx = months.indexOf(strDate);
```

Thereafter you can use `SimpleDateFormat("MMMM")` pattern to put and get it into your map.

```
if(idx > -1) {
    String longDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(retrievedate);
    Integer current = numberOfPost.get(longDate);
    if (current == null) {
        current = 1;
    } else {
        current += 1;
    }
    numberOfPost.put(longDate, current);
}
```

Thereafter, you can use map iterator to display content of map.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a good start. Using a the hash map will make the code much tidier. 
You can replace all those if statements and put statements with the code below:

```
if (!numberOfPosts.containsKey(strDate)) {
    numberOfPosts.put(strDate, 0);
}
numberOfPosts.put(strDate, numberOfPosts.get(strDate) + 1);
```

The if statement will create a dictionary entry if there is not one with the key of `strDate`. The value of the entry is set to 0.

```
numberOfPosts.put(strDate, numberOfPosts.get(strDate) + 1)
```

The line above increments by 1 the dictionary entry with the key of `strDate`.